# Installing 32 bit Python on 64 bit Fedora

Tags: python, vim, fedora

I have done a lot of digging and I can't seem to get any solutions to work. The one that looks the most promising is [this one](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-2928) starting from "32 bit Python". However when I run the `yum install` command listed there I get

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for glibc which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of glibc of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude glibc.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of glibc installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of glibc installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.18-11.fc20.i686 != glibc-2.18-12.fc20.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: glibc-headers-2.18-11.fc20.i686 != glibc-headers-2.18-12.fc20.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: glibc-common-2.18-11.fc20.i686 != glibc-common-2.18-12.fc20.x86_64
```

Does anyone know how to get 32 bit Python installed on a 64 bit machine? This is mainly to just get some Vim plugins to work properly (require 32 bit python).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the 64 bit libraries and development headers installed for libc common - you need to install the 32 bit (i686) versions yum, or another package manager, should let you specify that you need that version - alternatively you can download that specific package [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25593238/dir/fedora_20/com/glibc-common-2.18-12.fc20.x86_64.rpm.html) as an rpm.

Comment: Fortran? Odd that Fortran would affect this, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: @thaweatherman: Thanks for pointing that out - corrected - I miss-read the file name - it is a libc common package.

Comment: So if I install the 32 bit glibc-common I will be good to go? Also, will that prevent me from using the normal 64 bit glibc-common?